# How to generate Microsoft Help 3 file?

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

Microsoft Help 3 was shipped with Visual Studio 2010. How can I generate MSHC documentation file from XML documentation file? I have been using Sandcastle Help File Builder to generate CHM documentation file, but CHM is a li'l bit obsolete. Does anyone have skills with MS Help 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sandcastle Help File Builder to build all kind of help files - Help1, Help2, Help3 and web

Answer (score 0):

I think DocumentX from [Innovasys](http://www.innovasys.com) is really good. We've been using it for years.